# Remove duplicates form arraystring

Tags: java, duplicates, webdynpro

I have filled in an `ArrayList` of strings with suppliernumbers. This list contains duplicates values so I want to delete them with the `HashSet`.

I get following error: Invalid expression as statement
On line => Set set = new HashSet(leveranciers); (Set underlined)
Any idea why?

```
String[] leveranciers = new String[wdContext.nodeShoppingCart().size()];

for(int i = 0; i<wdContext.nodeShoppingCart().size(); i++){

      String productnumber = wdContext.nodeShoppingCart().getShoppingCartElementAt(i).getMatnr()

      wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().GetDetails(productnumber, "NL");
      leveranciers[i] = wdContext.currentEt_DetailsElement().getLifnr();
}

 //Remove duplicates from array
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(leveranciers);
        set.toArray(new String[0]);


for(int y = 0; y<set.size();y++){
    PdfPTable table = GetTable(set[y]);
    byte[] pdf = wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().GetPDFFromFolder("/intranetdocuments/docs/AchatsIndirect", table);
    wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().PrintPDF(pdf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HashSet doesn't have a constructor which accepts an array.
Have a look at HashSet documentation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

You can achieve your goal by using `Arrays.asList` method like that:

```
final String[] strings = new String[] {"ab", "ba", "ab"};
final Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

Comment: Still the same problem
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(leveranciers));